# Erro ao startar o react

Tags: javascript, react, npm

Quando tento startar o react depois de ter feito create-react-app e de ja ter criado a pasta aparece esse erro

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\LUIS MARQUES\Documents\JS\curso\udemy
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! exercicios@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the exercicios@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is li

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Sendo que o arquivo package.json esta assim:

```
{
  "name": "exercicios",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },

  "scripts":{
    "start":"react-scripts start",
    "build":"react-scripts build",
    "test":"react-scripts test",
    "eject":"react-scripts eject"
  }

}
```

Comment: nao tem muito o que dizer... arquivo não encontrado.
O C.R.A. cria uma pasta "static" que deveria ter um index.html dentro. Se não tiver, pode ter acontecido algum problema na criação do projeto... apenas meu chute.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que criar uma pasta chamada **public** com o arquivo **index.html**.

Aqui está a estrutura do arquivo em HTML que você que tem que criar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title> MEU SIT </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Você tem que também que criar os arquivo manifest.json e o favicon.ico

Mas para tornar sua vida mais fácil e sem complicações você deveria usar o própio pacote NPX que o ReactJS oferece para você.

[Na documentação oficial do ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) você pode encontrar um guia que é muito fácil de se entender e muito fácil de seguir, e dê uma lida na documentação antes de começar usar para entender como funciona os ciclos de vida.

Comment: Eu ja tinha usado o npx mas mesmo assim nao deu certo

Comment: Usa  ```npx create-react-app my_app``` e posta a saida do comando para a gente?

Comment: Esta na resposta ali abaixo,porem depois disso quando entro na pasta que criei e dou npm start ele da o mesmo erro que postei

Comment: Você pode postar a resposta da instalação para a gente dá uma olhada?

Comment: Coloquei  ali em baixo, ele nem gera os scripts no package.json, mas mesmo quando coloquei manualmente e depois rodei a instalaçao deu erro

Comment: Se o que tu ta falando é o seu ultimo comentário, aquilo é saida do comand do yarn e não do npx.

Comment: Ah sim desculpa achei que tinha colocado,quando dou npm start ele da esse erro: 


npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LUIS MARQUES\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-28T17_54_05_939Z-debug.log

Comment: O que tem dentro do debug.log? Você abriu para dá uma olhada?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você de esqueceu de entrar dentro da pasta que o crete-react-app criou. Após dar o comando `create-react-app`, digite no prompt de comando: `cd pasta-do-seu-app` e dê enter. Digite `npm start` novamente e veja se funciona.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, o que postei é o erro resultante apos ter feito isso

Answer (score 0):

```js
yarn add v1.19.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev 
|| >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.19.2", while you're on "1.19.0".
info To upgrade, download the latest installer at "https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi".
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ react-dom@16.12.0
├─ react-scripts@3.2.0
└─ react@16.12.0
info All dependencies
├─ react-app-polyfill@1.0.4
├─ react-dev-utils@9.1.0
├─ react-dom@16.12.0
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.3
├─ react-scripts@3.2.0
├─ react@16.12.0
└─ scheduler@0.18.0
Done in 236.05s.
```